# How to stop iteration on error | Node.js and MongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

Got a little problem here that's taking me too long to solve. I might be an idiot because i feel that this is a simple problem but i just cant wrap my head around it. So here's the code:

```
 get_online = function (err, result) {
        if (err) {
            return next(err);
        }
        streamers_size = result.length;
        result.map(
            function (entry) {
                curl.get
                    .to('https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/' + entry.uname)
                    .then(update_streamers);
            }
        );
    },

    update_streamers = function (err, result) {
        var clean;
        if (err) {
            return next(err);
        }
        if (result.stream) {
            db.collection('streamers').update({
                _id: result.stream.channel._id
            }, {
                $set: {
                    stream_preview: result.stream.preview.large,
                    viewers: result.stream.viewers
                }
            }, send_response);
        }
        else {
            clean = result._links.channel.substring(result._links.channel.length, 38);
            db.collection('streamers').update({
                uname: clean
            }, {
                $set: {
                    stream_preview: 'offline',
                    viewers: 0
                }
            }, send_response);
        }
    },
```

What's happening is that everytime a failed request to the api fires up the update_streamers callback and triggers the if(err), it's going to send the headers back: `return next(err)`, but what if the failed requests are consecutive? Therefore it'll send the headers back repetitively until i get an error that says `Can't send headers that are already set blah blah`. This is more of a logical question more than anything. So the question is, how do I stop the iteration (as mentioned in the title). Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What does `curl.get` do? Does it return a promise?

Answer (score 0):

Create a variable `errorCount` and initialize it to 0. Whenever you get an error, increase it. If it is 5, then stop trying. If there is a success, set `errorCount` to 0.

Answer (score 0):

maybe try

```
if(typeof err == "undefined")
```

sorry not sure of the full implementation in my head. 
the if(err) version will fire if a variable named err exists in that function scope ie. if the calling code sends a variable that is not false / undefined / "" / null.

not sure if you want to allow this

or maybe even

```
err = err || false;
```

this line will fire when err is null / "" / undefined / false
and sets it to false.